# Sorting by Last Name in the Scond Column

Tags: text-processing, sort

I'm trying to sort a file that has entries that look like so:

```
Essie    |   Vaill   |    14225 Hancock Dr       |      Anchorage  |   AK  |   99515 907-345-0962
```

Please note the "|" stand for tabs of various sizes.  I'm trying to sort this by the second field which in this case are last names in alphabetical order.  I've tried several different commands such as (note addresses.txt is the name of the file):

```
sort -k 2 addresses.txt
sort -t$'\t' -k2 addresses.txt
sort -t "`/bin/echo '\t'`" -k 2 addresses.txt
```

None of these are giving me the desired result and after searching the internet, I simply cannot find a solution that works the way I need it to.  If anyone could help me find the way to sort these by the second column in alphabetical order, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried `sort -k2,2 addresses.txt`?

Comment: Can you give your test and output?

Comment: this command also did not work.          sort -k2,2 addresses.txt

Comment: with all of these what ends up happening is that it sorts the last names in an odd way,with the last names not being in the order they are supposed to be in and the first column being sorted in what appears to be the shortest names first and the longest names last.  For example, first name Sue is first and first name Zachary is last

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try:

```
sort -t"|" -k2 address.txt
```

I think this shall do it

Comment: Well the "|" stands for tabs of space, so it doesn't really work, so when I Tried that it ended up sorting by first name or the first column

Comment: @MaximillianFargo I tried making a dummy address.txt file, it somehow worked. Actually, I was able to sort using that. Please notice that I am using double quotes. I am not sure if this is relevant, but you are using single quotes in your statements.

Comment: No I am using double quotes, the issue is that in the actual txt file, the columns aren't separated by "|", they are separated by simply blanks spaces.  The actual txt file does not have the "|" anywhere in it

Comment: @MaximillianFargo Then you can change the delimiter. -t" " or -t"\t" might help you get it done. I thought that the line you pasted above was extracted from the file of concern. You can set the delimiter to anything that is in the file, and see if it works :)

Comment: When using "\t" i get this message 
    sort: multi-character tab `\\t'

Comment: and using a simple " " also just sorted them by the first column

Comment: @MaximillianFargo Please try(with no quotes): -t \t

Comment: It did something different.  The last names start out looking like they will work( starts with Behen and Brevard) but then it immediately jumps to names like Vaill and then Rocheford

Comment: If the tab width is fixed, can please try delimiting by literally including it. For example, let's say the tabs are 4 chars wide then use 4 spaces as a delimiter:  -t"    "

Comment: I get the same error as before with "\t", sort: multi-character tab `    ', except this time with the spaces instead of the \t

Comment: @MaximillianFargo Are there names with more than one word? Like Chinese names that contain two words?? I have tried with a test file to sort things with R and V to see an error and it worked fine. Are there any first names that are of more than one word?

Comment: I'm looking at the file and there are several things i think might cause errors, but to double check I'm going to have to ask my professor about the file.  I believe the commands are correct, it's just something weird with the file

Comment: @MaximillianFargo Good luck, Max. It could be an encoding thing.

Answer (score 0):

A more generalized approach in Perl. This might help you in case the blanks are encoded differently from regular spaces or tabs:

```
perl -aF'[[:blank:]]+' -nle '
    $lines{$_}=[@F];
    END{
        print for sort { $lines{$a}[1] cmp $lines{$b}[1] } keys %lines
    }' your_file
```

I can't vouch for how it will scale compared to a `sort`-based solution, though.